# Does nsuserdefaults gets persisted when user restore app

Tags: nsuserdefaults

In ios, If the user backups an application and restores the backup, will the data in NSUserDefault will get persisted?  If yes, How to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

The NSUserDefaults are stored in the backup and therefore will be restored as well.